# How to set up a private cloud using opennebula

Tags: build, configuration, cloud, setup-deployment, opennebula

I want to set up a private cloud using 3 desktop machines using opennebula (or openstack) cloud platform.
One will be the front-end and 2 nodes.

But i don't have idea how can i configure/connect these machines (in terms of hardware) together to build that cloud environment.

I would like to know how can i realize this configuration to obtain/build my own private cloud and what are the steps?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't prefer the official documentation of the thing you are asking to implement.
You can simply follow the clear steps from https://docs.opennebula.org/5.6/intro_release_notes/concepts_terminology/intro.html#step-1-choose-your-hypervisor

I hope you have got your answer and prefer to ask any doubts if that deals some serious implementation!